# How to update sqlite3 record in python using WHERE?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sql-update

I am struggeling with updating a record in my sqlite3 database in python.
I have tried to follow this [tutorial](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/create-tables/) and modify this function from the tutorial for my needs:

```
def update_task(conn, task):
    """
    update priority, begin_date, and end date of a task
    :param conn:
    :param task:
    :return: project id
    """
    sql = ''' UPDATE tasks
              SET priority = ? ,
                  begin_date = ? ,
                  end_date = ?
              WHERE id = ?'''
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql, task)
    conn.commit()
```

I have a table set up like this:

```
sql_create_answers_table = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS answers (
                                    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
                                    predmet text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                                    tag text NOT NULL,
                                    keyword text NOT NULL,
                                    obsah text NOT NULL,
                                    autor text NOT NULL,
                                    datum text NOT NULL
                                );"""
db.create_table(sql_create_answers_table)
```

I have my update function written like this:

```
def update_answer(answer):
    try:
        conn = create_connection(db_name)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        sql_command = """UPDATE answers 
                        SET predmet = ? ,
                            tag = ? ,
                            keyword = ? ,
                            obsah = ? ,
                            autor = ? ,
                            datum = ? ,
                        WHERE id = ?"""
        # I have also tried this: cur.execute(sql_command, answer )
        cur.execute(sql_command, (answer[1], answer[2], answer[3], answer[4], answer[5], answer[6], answer[0]) )
        conn.commit()                        
        conn.close()
    finally:
        unlock_db()
```

This is how I establishe the connection to the database:

```
def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to an SQLite database """
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return conn
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
```

When I call the function in my tkinter app, the original answer looks like this:

```
(1, 'pokus', 'žádný', 'datum', 'Text zpravy a ahoj kamo.\n', 'Vlad', '02/09/21')
```

Then I create a new version of the answer that looks like this:

```
new_answer = (1, 'pokus', 'žádný', 'datum', 'Text\n', 'Vlad', '02/15/21') # the 4th field changes
```

And then call the update function (db is my imported module with the function):

```
db.update_answer(new_answer)
```

I am getting an Error "

```
File "f:\AAA Vlada\a škola\Python\zapoctak\db_module.py", line 135, in update_answer
    cur.execute(sql_command, (answer[1], answer[2], answer[3], answer[4], answer[5], answer[6], answer[0]) )
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error
```

"

Other operations on my database work normally and I do not understand why this simple update function doesnt work. The "updated answer" seems to me to be made correctly and so does the update function.

I am gratefull for any help and I can provide more code if necesary.

Comment: ``datum = ? , WHERE id`` -> get rid of the ``,`` before ``WHERE``

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was rather an easy solution but I couldnt find it for hours :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the extra `,` character just before `WHERE` clause and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really missed this during my multiple checks against the code in the tutorial. Have a good day.